# opencv single edge detection and contour extraction without closed contour

Tags: python, opencv, edge-detection

I'm having trouble extracting a contour from this and other similar streak images.
[image]

First I tried this:

```py
edges = cv2.Canny(cvimg, 150, 600)
plt.subplot(111)
plt.imshow(cvimg,cmap = 'gray')
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# get the contour that has the least mean y value, which should be the upper most contour
avg_y = [cont.T[1].mean() for cont in contours]
idx = np.argmin(avg_y)
contour = np.asarray(contours[idx]).squeeze().T # reshape and reorient for plotting
plt.plot(contour[0], contour[1], color="r")
plt.show()
```

On first glance this solution works:
[image: contour][image: edge]
But here both the upper and underside of the canny edge are part of a closed-loop contour. I cannot easily separate the two sides. At least nothing comes to mind.

My second try was to threshold the image and not use canny at all:

```py
_, cvimg = cv2.threshold(cvimg, 50, 255, type=cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(cvimg, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# get the contour that has the least mean y value, which should be the upper most contour
avg_y = [cont.T[1].mean() for cont in contours]
idx = np.argmin(avg_y)
contour = np.asarray(contours[idx]).squeeze().T
plt.plot(contour[0], contour[1], color="r")
plt.show()
```

But that also yields a closed contour:

[image]

As the last try I used the canny filtered image and just took the first nonzero index in every column:

```py
edges = cv2.Canny(cvimg, 150, 600)
contour = np.argmax(edges>0, axis=0)
plt.subplot(111)
plt.imshow(cvimg,cmap = 'gray')
plt.plot(contour, color="r")
plt.show()
```

This is also not ideal, since there is too much being detected on both sides.
[image]

How can I get just the upper V shape contour, so I don't have to do postprocessing which might not work for all my data? Is there a way to tell OpenCV to not loop around the Canny edges? Or am I just too dumb to use the library correctly?
Thanks!

Comment: Please specify how you want the bottom of the V to be handled.

Comment: I don't need it, I only need the top part.

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Comment: If you look at the second image, the red line is the contour I want.

Comment: Use the second method and split the contour where it follows the image outline.

Answer (score 0):

I found a method that works:

I'm now using a different thresholding, which inverts the image. Now the contour just encloses the V shape. I don't have to split it, just remove all points on the image border.

```py
# binary threshold, inverting
_, cvimg = cv2.threshold(cvimg, 1, 255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(cvimg.astype(np.uint8), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
plt.imshow(cvimg,cmap = 'gray')

# get the contour that has the least mean y value, which should be the upper most contour
avg_y = [cont.T[1].mean() for cont in contours]
idx = np.argmin(avg_y)
contour = np.asarray(contours[idx]).squeeze().T

# remove contour parts that touch the image border
del_pos = np.argwhere(contour[1]==0)
contour = np.delete(contour.T, del_pos, axis=0).T

# remove duplicate x values
unique_x, idx = np.unique(contour[0], return_index=True)
contour_clean = contour.T[idx].T

plt.plot(contour_clean[0], contour_clean[1], color="r")
```